# How far back is it acceptable to ask a followup on a question?

Tags: discussion

Say I have an issue, and I find a helpful question and answer that was posted in 2015. There being back and forth on the answer is it proper to join the comments asking for followup today in 2017 or is it best to open a new question?

Comment: If you check the users profile, you can see the last time they were active on the site. That can be helpful in determining follow-up steps.

Comment: By the way, comments don't always notify the poster (I've missed several comments this way, often to find them months or years later), so it's generally more reliable to ask a new question anyways, using Adrian's advice. We'd rather close duplicates than have your answer go unnoticed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I wouldn't say there's a hard limit, but it's more about how involved your follow up is and how frequently those members contribute. In general, if your follow up can't be answered in one line, ask a new question. Make sure you link to the old one if it helps provide context, otherwise it might get mistaken as a duplicate.

Comment: It was a Keith C answer so I know he's around, It felt weird to follow up from so far back. Thanks for the guidance.

Comment: @DanWooding Can't find it again now, but if it is the one I think it was my lack of response was because I was busy that day on paid work and your question was a good one that would require some time to answer... If the follow up was within a few days so the original was fresh in my mind I probably would have answered. A benefit of asking a new question (linked to the old) is that it gets many people considering an answer so ups the odds.